# "The request must contain the parameter MessageHandle" error when deleting a message from an AWS SQS queue (in Coldfusion)

Tags: amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-sqs

I'm struggling to delete a message once received from an AWS queue.

The function I'm using is:

```
<cffunction name="deleteMessage" output="true" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="uri" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="messageId" type="string" required="true">

    <cfset var tmp = StructNew()/>

    <cfset tmp.dateTimeString = zuluDateTimeFormat(Now())/>

    <cfset tmp.fixedData = "ActionDeleteMessage" &
                                "AWSAccessKeyId#This.awsAccessKeyId#" &
                                "MessageHandle#Arguments.messageId#" &
                                "SignatureVersion1" &
                                "Timestamp#tmp.dateTimeString#" &
                                "Version#This.sqsVersion#"/>

    <cfset tmp.signature = createSignature(tmp.fixedData)/>

    <cfhttp method="GET" url="#Arguments.host#" charset="UTF-8">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Action" value="DeleteMessage"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="#This.awsAccessKeyId#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="MessageHandle" value="#Arguments.messageId#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Signature" value="#tmp.signature#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="SignatureVersion" value="1"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Timestamp" value="#tmp.dateTimeString#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Version" value="#This.sqsVersion#"/>
    </cfhttp>

    <cfdump var="#CFHTTP.FileContent#"><cfabort>

    <cfif CFHTTP.ResponseHeader.Status_Code neq 200>
        <cfinvoke method="handleErrors"
            content="#CFHTTP.FileContent#"
        />
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn XmlParse(CFHTTP.FileContent).deleteMessageResponse.return.XmlText/>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

All the details are being passed in correctly and the signature is also being generated successfully (verified through other AWS calls). The error message I get back from Amazon is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2008-01-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>MissingParameter</Code><Message>The request must contain the parameter MessageHandle.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>1a144095-db82-59c1-9551-116614ba674d</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
```

How do I correct this problem and correctly delete the message?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you need both MessageHandle and ReceiptHandle in the request:

```
<cffunction name="deleteMessage" output="true" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="uri" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="messageId" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="receiptHandle" type="string" required="true">

    <cfset var tmp = StructNew()/>

    <cfset tmp.dateTimeString = zuluDateTimeFormat(Now())/>

    <cfset tmp.fixedData = "ActionDeleteMessage" &
                                "AWSAccessKeyId#This.awsAccessKeyId#" &
                                "MessageHandle#Arguments.messageId#" &
                                "ReceiptHandle#Arguments.receiptHandle#" &
                                "SignatureVersion1" &
                                "Timestamp#tmp.dateTimeString#" &
                                "Version#This.sqsVersion#"/>

    <cfset tmp.signature = createSignature(tmp.fixedData)/>

    <cfhttp method="GET" url="#Arguments.host#" charset="UTF-8">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Action" value="DeleteMessage"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="#This.awsAccessKeyId#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="MessageHandle" value="#Arguments.messageId#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="ReceiptHandle" value="#Arguments.receiptHandle#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Signature" value="#tmp.signature#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="SignatureVersion" value="1"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Timestamp" value="#tmp.dateTimeString#"/>
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="Version" value="#This.sqsVersion#"/>
    </cfhttp>

    <cfdump var="#CFHTTP.FileContent#"><cfabort>

    <cfif CFHTTP.ResponseHeader.Status_Code neq 200>
        <cfinvoke method="handleErrors"
            content="#CFHTTP.FileContent#"
        />
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn XmlParse(CFHTTP.FileContent).deleteMessageResponse.return.XmlText/>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: The old misleading error message.  Gets them every time.

Comment: As of May 2023, the documentation for the V3 JS SDK is still missing this information. It documents ReceiptHandle and QueueUrl as the only 2 available parameters for this command, yet the response complains that MessageHandle is missing. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sqs/interfaces/deletemessagecommandinput.html